# Mocking DateFormat, SimpleDateFormat, Date class

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, powermockito

I need to mock the required class(es) and get the desired date result.

I've already tried mocking the format() function in the DateFormat class but didn't work.

```
class XYZ {

   private static final DateFormat DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
   private static final TimeZone UTC = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");

   public void buildStr(StringBuilder str){
     DATE_FORMAT.setTimeZone(UTC);
     Date date = getDate();
     str.append(DATE_FORMAT.format(date));
   }

   private Date getDate(){
     return new Date();
   }

}
```

In this code I expect the star to be appended with "20190430000000" (exactly this value)
but I'm getting the current UTC time.

Comment: No, you do not need to mock DateFormat, SimpleDateFormat or Date. You should not even *use* SimpleDateFormat. You should have a `Clock` which you can easily mock / create dummy instance via `Clock.fixed(...)`.

Comment: Do you want to write a test with a mock as indicated in the title or do you simply want to create an instance of `Date` with a fixed date?

Comment: I've seen similar stack overflow questions but am unable to replicate them in my scenario.

Comment: @cmoetzing I want to write a test with a mock and append str with "20190430000000" instead of current date and time as opposed to the requirement in my actual service.

Comment: @luk2302
Is there a way of doing it qithout Clock class lib

Comment: Clock is no lib, it is in java.time, you can use it without any problems.

Comment: @AnkitGupta What java version are you working with?

Comment: your example shows exactly zero mocks, obviously you cant mock anything. It also shows not a single piece of code which does anything to reach your goal. Another thing : that is not a unit test. Methinks you need to start from scratch ... maybe try compile and run a hello-world app and follow tutorials about programming.

Comment: @specializt 
I've not included any test class in this code.
I wanted to know if someone could help me provide a piece of code that could actually help in receiving the desired date values in "str" by stubbing or mocking. This is not a test class, just a worker class.

Comment: @cmoetzing
It's 1.8

Answer (score 0):

You could use a fixed date

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse("20190430000000", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmss"));
```

This code example will work with java8 or higher.

**EDIT1:**

**Assumption:** You want to write a test that uses a fixed date yet in production uses the current date. You can use JUnit, dependency injection of some sort and Mockito.

This is an abstract example which won't compile directly.

```
class XYZ {
    @Inject
    private DateProvider dateProvider;

    public void buildStr(StringBuilder str){
        LocalDate date = dateProvider.getDate();

        // do something with date
    }
}

class DateProvider {
    public Date getDate() {
        return new Date();
    }
}

class XYZTest {
    @Mock
    private DateProvider dateProvider;

    @InjectMocks
    private XYZ xyz;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        LocalDate fixedDate = LocalDate.parse("20190430000000", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmss"));
        when(dateProvider.getDate()).thenReturn(fixedDate);

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        xyz.buildStr(builder);

        // verify builder contains what you expect
    }
}
```

In your service class you define an additional component which provides the date (here `DateProvider`). In the test you get a testable instance of your service via the annotation `@InjectMocks` provided by Mocktio. It will inject any field annotated with `@Mock` into your testable instance as a mock. In your test you define what the mock is supposed to do by `when().thenReturn()`. Your production code will use the actual implementation of `DateProvider` and you get the current date.

Comment: I don't want the date to be fixed for actual service.
It's just while writing the test case that I need this specific value to be set

Comment: @AnkitGupta You question never really mentions or shows a test so I update my answer based on assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

## *java.time*

You are using terrible date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes as defined in JSR 310.

## `Clock`

The *java.time* classes take an optional [`Clock`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Clock.html) argument. Pass a `Clock` object with the behavior you need for your test. The `Clock` class has static methods providing several special behaviors. These include a fixed moment, a rolling moment set a certain amount of time ahead or behind the true clock, and altered cadence such as incrementing on whole minutes.

This has been covered many times already on Stack Overflow. Search to learn more.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2019 , Month.APRIL , 30 ) ;
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Edmonton" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ld.atStartOfDay( z ) ;
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant() ;
Clock clock = Clock.fixed( instant , z ) ;
```

Now inject that `clock` object in your tests.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( clock ) ;
```

When you want a true clock, use:

```
Clock clock = Clock.system( z ) ;
```